# How to get value from array with objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I try to use api.openweathermap.org for get current weather. I use a php request to get a data. I sucessfully receive data and convert it to array with   objects.  I have a small question: How to get a value of  key named "MAIN", which is equal to "Snow"?
I try to use api.openweathermap.org for get current weather. I use a php request to get a data. I sucessfully receive data and convert it to array with   objects.  I have a small question: How to get a value of  key named "MAIN", which is equal to "Snow"?

```
object(stdClass)#3 (14) {
  ["coord"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["lon"]=>
    float(30.2642)
    ["lat"]=>
    float(59.8944)
  }
  ["weather"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(600)
      ["main"]=>
      string(4) "Snow"
      ["description"]=>
      string(27) "small snow"
      ["icon"]=>
      string(3) "13n"
    }
  }
  ["base"]=>
  string(8) "stations"
  ["main"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (6) {
    ["temp"]=>
    float(-11.94)
    ["feels_like"]=>
    float(-18.94)
    ["temp_min"]=>
    float(-15.2)
    ["temp_max"]=>
    float(-11.08)
    ["pressure"]=>
    int(1010)
    ["humidity"]=>
    int(86)
  }
  ["visibility"]=>
  int(10000)
  ["wind"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["speed"]=>
    int(4)
    ["deg"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  ["snow"]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
    ["1h"]=>
    float(0.5)
  }
  ["clouds"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
    ["all"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  ["dt"]=>
  int(1641652836)
  ["sys"]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (5) {
    ["type"]=>
    int(2)
    ["id"]=>
    int(197864)
    ["country"]=>
    string(2) "RU"
    ["sunrise"]=>
    int(1641624902)
    ["sunset"]=>
    int(1641647737)
  }
  ["timezone"]=>
  int(10800)
  ["id"]=>
  int(498817)
  ["name"]=>
  string(29) "SPb"
  ["cod"]=>
  int(200)
}
```

Comment: This isn't an array, it's an object. I recommend having a look at some introductory PHP tutorials, which will show you how to get properties of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value like this :

```php
$weatherType = $weather->weather[0]->main;
```